# Integral inequality $\int_0^x{f(t)^3 dt \leq \left( \int_0^x f(t) dt\right)^2} :\forall x>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, derivatives

Let $f(0) = 0$ and $0<f'(x)\leq1$ for all $x \geq0$, then prove:

$$\int_0^x{f(t)^3 dt \leq \left( \int_0^x f(t) dt\right)^2} :\forall x>0$$

The hint I was given was "differentiate, factor and differentiate again" but I'm not sure where to start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\left(\int_0^xf(t)dt\right)^2-\int_0^xf(t)^3dt$. We want to show $g(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$. Clearly $g(0)=0$, so it suffices to show $g'(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$. Differentiating, we get
$$g'(x)=2f(x)\int_0^xf(t)dt-f(x)^3=f(x)\left[2\int_0^xf(t)dt-f(x)^2\right].$$
Since $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x)>0$ for all $x\geq0$, $f(x)\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$. So all that is left is to show $h(x)=2\int_0^xf(t)dt-f(x)^2\geq0$ for all $x\geq0$, which you can do in more or less the same way.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!!

Comment: It seems like I am missing something very fundamental in calculus, but why aren't both parts equal? We now, that both f(x) and f^3(x) are continuous and bounded on [0,x]. This means that we can apply fundamental theorem of calculus (its second part) and get (f(x)^4)/4 = (f(x)^4)/4

Comment: Correct me if I've misinterpreted, but it seems like you're asking why we don't just say $\int f(x)^3=\frac{f(x)^4}4$ and $\int f(x)=\frac{f(x)^2}2$. You're forgetting about the chain rule. If you differentiate $\frac{f(x)^2}2$ with respect to $x$, you get $f(x)\cdot f'(x)$, so we only have $\int f(x)=\frac{f(x)^2}2$ if $f'(x)=1$, i.e. if $f(x)=x+c$.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. I somehow took $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ as $\int_0^x f(t) df(t)$